# How to Add TaxAmount on subtotal in xero api

Tags: php, xero-api

How can we directly add TAX AMOUNT{20} on SUBTOTAL. 
In palce of line item, i directly want to add TaxAmount on subtotal, when we set "NO VAT" on Tax Rate in xero api.

please suggest .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xero works by calculating the totals and subtotals based on the line items. It is not possible to overwrite totals and subtotals.

You will need to add an extra line item for rounding.